# Best way to transform this json with lodash

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, lodash

I am starting with `lodash` and I need to transform this json:

```
{
    "keyA": "valA",
    "keyB": [
        "valB1",
        "valB2",
        "valB3",
        "valB4",
    ],
    "keyC": [
        "valC1",
        "valC2",
        "valC3",
        "valC4",
    ],
    "...": ["...","...","...","..."],
    "keyD": "valD"
}
```

to this json:

```
[
    {
        "keyB":"valB1",
        "keyC":"valC1"
    },
    {
        "keyB":"valB2",
        "keyC":"valC2"
    },
    {
        "keyB":"valB3",
        "keyC":"valC3"
    },
    {
        "keyB":"valB4",
        "keyC":"valC4"
    },
]
```

**`keyB`, `keyC` and other array keys always have the same size.**

**Those keys which are not arrays I have to ignore them.**

any idea? thanks.

Comment: The arrays always have the same size and are in the correct sequential order like in the example?

Comment: Yes, same size and same order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var o = {
    "keyA": "valA",
    "keyB": [
        "valB1",
        "valB2",
        "valB3",
        "valB4",
    ],
    "keyC": [
        "valC1",
        "valC2",
        "valC3",
        "valC4",
    ],
    "keyD": "valD",
    "keyE": [
        "valE1",
        "valE2",
        "valE3",
        "valE4",
    ]
};

var r = [];

_.each(o, function(v, k) {
   if (_.isArray(v)) {
       _.each(v, function(v2, i) {
           r.length <= i && r.push({});
           r[i][k] = v2;
       });
   }
});

console.log(r);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ferahl/1rjx3tL8/